Why the same PowerShell path sometimes works and sometimes does not?
I am new to PowerShell (coming from Bash), and I cannot understand why a path I build sometimes works and others does not:
PS > E:\Installers\wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe --version
GNU Wget 1.19.1 built on mingw32.
...OK

PS > $rootPath = E:\Installers
PS > echo ${rootPath}
E:\Installers
PS > dir ${rootPath}\wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe


    Directory: E:\Installers\wget


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                        
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                        
-a----        19/04/2024     15:50        3481920 wget-win32-1.19.1.exe

PS > ${rootPath}\wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe --version
At line:1 char:12
+ ${rootPath}\wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe --version
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Why does ${rootPath} work with dir and not on its own?

Are you using a PowerShell console? There is no 'PS' at the beginning of the command prompt. What is the output of $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()? The statement $rootPath = E:\Installers is not valid. Quotation is required with either QUOTATION MARK or APOSTROPHE characters.

& $rootPath\wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe --version

@lit - I fixed the prompt. The output of $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString() is
5.1.19041.1320



Why does ${rootPath} work with dir and not on its own?

This is explained in Argument mode from the about Parsing documentation. In particular, the bullet point:


Everything else is treated as an expandable string, except metacharacters that still need escaping. See Handling special characters.


So, essentially, the argument passed to dir (Get-ChildItem) is interpreted as if it was an expandable string "${rootPath}\wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe":
$rootPath = 'E:\Installers'
& {param([string] $path) $path } ${rootPath}\wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe

# Parameter binding resolves the concatenation as:
# `E:\Installers\wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe`

However in your second attempt PowerShell can't determine that what you're trying to do is create a new string by concatenating the variable value ${rootPath} with the rest of the string \wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe, you need to help it by wrapping the expression in an expandable string and then invoking that path either with dot-sourcing operator . or call operator & both detailed in about Operators:
& "${rootPath}\wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe" --version

Other alternative could be to use Join-Path:
& (Join-Path ${rootPath} wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe) --version

Or, perhaps invoking the command info instance, here PowerShell auto-resolves the path to winget for you:
& (Get-Command winget) --version


The last example using Get-Command is handy, but it only works if the directory of the executable (winget in this case) is in the Env:Path variable.

yep but this would usually be the case, winget already comes with windows by default right? and ...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ is by default part of the path env variable

Powershell requires the call operator for variables and strings:
$rootPath = 'E:\Installers'

& $rootPath\wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe --version
& 'e:\installers\wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe' --version

Without the call operator:
e:\installers\wget\wget-win32-1.19.1.exe --version

$env:path += ';e:\installers\wget'  # temporary, or add it in the gui
wget-win32-1.19.1.exe --version

Note that wget is an alias for Invoke-WebRequest.
